# Is this a right proof proving that if $A\rightarrow False$ is true then A is logically equivalent to False?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Here's my proof:
$$\left(A\rightarrow \bot\right)\rightarrow\left( A\rightarrow \bot \wedge \bot\rightarrow A\right)$$
$$\left( A\rightarrow \bot \wedge \bot\rightarrow A\right)\rightarrow\left(A\equiv \bot\right)$$
both of statements are true so it proves that if $A\rightarrow \bot$ is true then $A\equiv \bot$ is also true which should mean A is logically equivalent to $\bot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is not correct because there is no rule saying that $A\to B \to((A\to B)\wedge(B\to A))$. On the other hand, the definition of $\to$ is
that $A\to B \equiv (\lnot A)\vee B$, so that

$A\to False \equiv (\lnot A)\vee False \equiv \lnot A$

You should be able to conclude.

*Use existing rules, don't use rules that don't exist!*

**Edit** Wikipedia calls the rule $A\to B \equiv (\lnot A)\vee B$ [*material implication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)). It is often the easiest way to handle $\to$ because the semantics of negation and the disjunction connector are straightforward.

**Edit 2** Following @AsafKaragila's comments, it occurs to me that the OP's proof may have used implicitly that $False \to A \equiv True$ so that $(A\to False) \wedge (False\to A)$ is equivalent to $A\to False$.
This may validate the original proof, but I still believe the proof with material implication is better.

Comment: I don't think it's a rule that you claim was made up, but more of a specific statement about falsehood and implications, which one can prove from existing rules.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you elaborate of the statement and the related rules?

Comment: $\bot\to p$ applied to $p=A$; therefore $A\to\bot\land\bot\to A$; now apply $p\to(q\to p)$ and modus ponens to obtain $A\to\bot\to(A\to\bot\land\bot\to A)$ (here $p=A\to\bot\land\bot\to A$ and $q=A\to\bot$).

Comment: @AsafKaragila See my edit above. You may be right, but I think it's much harder to understand what's going on with this computation.

Comment: Ofc I meant what you mentioned in Edit 2, thought it's obvious, I like your proof btw :)

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contradiction. Suppose A is true. Than false is true, which is a contradiction. A must be false.